# How can I get gmail to stop asking me this question on recovery email address being correct?

Tags: gmail, firefox

For the last few days, I am now suddenly getting the following alert in yellow at the top of my GMail session:

```
Hey, this is important: If you ever lose access to your account, we can send 
password reset info to xxx@xxx.edu. This address is correct | Update this address
```

I have clicked `This address is correct` multiple times but the message keeps returning and I tried `Update this address`, but I cannot update to the same address as it says there is no change.

How can I make this annoying message go away?  Is this an issue with cookies? I am running Firefox v9.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your Cache and Cookie. There has been similar questions on Google forum, and the same was suggested. and a top-contributor [also added](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=19ad946290bbde58&hl=en) that it might be a Gmail bug affecting few number of users.

Comment: I tried removing cookies with 'gmail' in their name, but it still fails. Are there other cookies to delete? I'd rather not delete them all. Also, how to you clear the cache?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Using Firefox v9.0.1

Comment: To clear cache, Click Firefox button > Options > Privacy > clear your recent history > set the Time range to clear: to Everything > In the list at the bottom of the window, uncheck everything except for Cache > Clear Now. Done. [Source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/maintenance/ht/clearcacheff.htm).